# Removing spaces within parentheses in VIM

Tags: linux, vim

I have a file which has unwanted spaces within the parentheses as shown below:

```
SUM(page_visits          ) ,
SUM(previews             ) ,
SUM(comments             ) ,
SUM(shared_items         ) ,
SUM(upload_bandwidth     ) ,
```

How do I remove these spaces in VIM editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the following command,

```
:1,$s/ *)/)/
```

There is a space before * in the command.

Comment: Awesome..thanks...it would be great if you could explain the command

Comment: The `:` starts an ex command.  The `1,$` is a line range meaning first line to the end of the file.  Then there is a blank space, which can be represented as `\s`, followed by * which means zero or more of the preceding char.  Finally, a `)`.  The second paren is what to replace the 1st part with.

Comment: To save another two keystrokes you could replace the `1,$` range with `%` wich is essentially the same.

Comment: Add flag `g` can be usefull too it you want to replace whole line. `%s/ *)/)/g`